# Publishing a webpage from GitHub

Tags: html, github, directory, repository, publishing

I created a repository in GitHub and then a new folder in that repository. I uploaded the necessary files (index.html, style.css and an image) in this folder. But whenever I tried to publish my webpage, I couldn’t.

Although there is no problem to publish it directly from the repository (without having another folder), when I try to publish it from the folder in a repository, I see the content of the "readme" in the browser. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The [publishing source for a GitHub pages project](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) is by default a branch.

Make sure to select your folder if you want to publish it from a directory:

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/pages/publishing-source-folder-drop-down.png]

But that folder might be limited to "`docs/`"